# How do I assign the value from one partner in dyad to the other partner in R (e.g. using dplyr)?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have data on individuals within dyads that look like this:

```
    out <- data.frame("id" = seq(1:8), 
                      dyad =rep(letters[1:4], each = 2, 
                      times = 1), 
                      income = rep(c(1000, 900), 4)
                      )
```

Which gives me:

| id | dyad | income |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1000 |
| 2 | a | 900 |
| 3 | b | 1000 |
| 4 | b | 900 |
| 5 | c | 1000 |
| 6 | c | 900 |
| 7 | d | 1000 |
| 8 | d | 900 |

Suppose further that I want a column that gives me each partner's income within each dyad. The new column would look like this:

```
out$income_partner <- rep(c(900, 1000), 4)
```

So that the data look like this:

| id | dyad | income | income_partner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1000 | 900 |
| 2 | a | 900 | 1000 |
| 3 | b | 1000 | 900 |
| 4 | b | 900 | 1000 |
| 5 | c | 1000 | 900 |
| 6 | c | 900 | 1000 |
| 7 | d | 1000 | 900 |
| 8 | d | 900 | 1000 |

Can anyone help me to map responses from one member of each dyad to the other member of each dyad?

Grateful in advance for any advice.

Comment: Jaco Pastorius. If one of the solutions solves your problem, please give them credit by at least choosing one as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve your problem as follow:

```
library(dplyr)

out %>%
  group_by(dyad) %>%
  mutate(income_partner = rev(income)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 8 x 4
     id dyad  income income_partner
  <int> <chr>  <dbl>          <dbl>
1     1 a       1000            900
2     2 a        900           1000
3     3 b       1000            900
4     4 b        900           1000
5     5 c       1000            900
6     6 c        900           1000
7     7 d       1000            900
8     8 d        900           1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `first` and `last`:

```r
out <- data.frame("id" = seq(1:8), 
                  dyad =rep(letters[1:4], each = 2, 
                            times = 1), 
                  income = rep(c(1000, 900), 4)
)

library(dplyr)
out %>%
  group_by(dyad) %>%
  mutate(income_partner = c(last(income), first(income))) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 8 × 4
#> # Groups:   dyad [4]
#>      id dyad  income income_partner
#>   <int> <chr>  <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1     1 a       1000            900
#> 2     2 a        900           1000
#> 3     3 b       1000            900
#> 4     4 b        900           1000
#> 5     5 c       1000            900
#> 6     6 c        900           1000
#> 7     7 d       1000            900
#> 8     8 d        900           1000
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

```
library(tidyverse)

out %>%
  group_by(dyad) %>%
  mutate(income_partner = income[3 - row_number()]) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 8 x 4
     id dyad  income income_partner
  <int> <chr>  <dbl>          <dbl>
1     1 a       1000            900
2     2 a        900           1000
3     3 b       1000            900
4     4 b        900           1000
5     5 c       1000            900
6     6 c        900           1000
7     7 d       1000            900
8     8 d        900           1000
```